# Re-organize certain file versions in Git

Tags: git

A Git branch has multiple commits and the development workflow is organized so that separate commits are dedicated to compiled executable file.

Yes, some earlier versions of this file need to be stored in Git, but there are also some intermediate versions which we will never refer to and they only bloat Git repository.

I am looking for a way to remove them from repo.

Comment: What files are we talking about? Text files or huge media files?

Comment: @knittl: One EXE file. It was written in the question.

Comment: You can use `git rebase -i` or `git filter-branch` to rewrite history. Be careful: rewriting published history is considered bad and can lead to unexpected results if another dev merges old and new history (e.g. with `git pull`).

Comment: Also consider moving compilation results out of your source repository.

Comment: @musiKk: It is convenient for me to keep compilation results in the same repository synchronized with source code from which it was compiled.

Comment: @Paul I prefer to use a CI server for that but fair enough. Then it's basically what knittl said. Interactive rebase is really awesome and powerful.